# SiteCore - JSON showing on the pages where controls should be in the page editor

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I'm in the page editor and I'm seeing JSON where editor controls should be

> {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:field:editcontrol({command:\"webedit:chooseimage\"})","header":"Choose
>   Image","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/photo_landscape.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Choose
>   an
>   image","type":null},{"click":"chrome:field:editcontrol({command:\"webedit:editimage\"})","header":"Properties","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/palette_preferences.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Modify
>   image
>   appearance","type":null},{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit
>   the related
>   item","icon":"/temp/IconCache/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit
>   this item in the Content
>   Editor.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{2D90E98C-1360-4EBA-855E-3B321B053376}?lang=en&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Logo","expandedDisplayName":null}

This is happening in the page editor but not when I view the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. It was because I removed the  < form method="post" runat="server" id="mainform" > from the page. Added it back in. Best if you make it the first child under < body >

Comment: I'm just curious, but why do you say you have the same issue while it was your own question? +1 for posting the solution anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I also recently encountered this issue and the resolution for me was to make sure the 'webedit.css' file existed at the location specified by the 'WebEdit.ContentEditorStylesheet' setting.

By default the webedit.css file is located at the root of your site, but in my instance the file had been moved.

Comment: thanks for sharing. We need more info on SiteCore. Their forums are not that great.

Answer (score 0):

We had this error because of commented out HTML above the DOCTYPE declaration.  Removing the commented out HTML fixed the problem.