# Sitecore Page Editor not loading

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I want to use the page editor for editting my pages. I'm using Sitecore MVC, so my layout is called default.cshtml. I have multiple placeholders in this layout.

I've checked my HTML and I've checked in the code if Sitecore is in PageEditorMode.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237344/sitecore-json-showing-on-the-pages-where-controls-should-be-in-the-page-editor) somebody has the same problem, but he's using Webforms.

This is the JSON I'm seeing in the page. Any ideas?

```
{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit the related item","icon":"/temp/IconCache/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_blue_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit this item in the Content Editor.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{9915C7DC-E1B4-48A5-807F-EDE309F9DE3C}?lang=en&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}
```

Comment: Is this an existing or new project? Did you verify the existence of `webedit.css` in the root folder?

Comment: just to be sure: did you configure (the correct) placeholder settings and is the rendering marked as editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks indeed like you're missing the webedit.css (and all other css & js files) like jammykam mentions.

Do you have the Sitecore.MvcExperienceEditor.config included? That will handle the rendering of those scripts & js files

Comment: webedit.css was present in de webroot.
<setting name="WebEdit.ContentEditorStylesheet" value="/webedit.css" /> is present in de web.config

Comment: Sorry, did not mean you missed it in your webroot. You're missing it in the page output. This is because you've not enabled the MVC experience editor (by including the config file mentioned above)

Comment: don't clean your sln :(

Answer (score 0):

A fairly common issue with Page Editor not loading is a conflict between jQuery and Prototype.  Please see the following post on how to resolve this conflict.

[jQuery conflicts with PageEditor](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/01/jquery-conflicts-with-pageeditor.html)